# Angular 6 filter table with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

[I have this working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpbzg8). I want to filter a table using checkboxes. The problem is when I check `a` for example, it gives me the filtered array. But when I uncheck it, I want to return me the original array.

.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups">
    <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
    <input type="checkbox" name="customersGroupFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="group" (change)="changeGroup($event)">
    {{ group }}
  </label>&nbsp;
</ng-container>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Group</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of newArray">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.group}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

.ts

```
  changeGroup(event) {
    const group = event.target.value;
    const index = this.groupValue.indexOf(group);

    if (index > -1) {
      this.groupValue.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.groupValue.push(group);
    }

    this.transform(this.usersList, 'group', this.groupValue)
  }

  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {
    console.log(value)
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
      return items;
    }

    this.newArray = items.filter(singleItem => {
      return (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && value.indexOf(singleItem[field]) >= 0);
    });

    return this.newArray
  }
```

How can I modify this code in order to obtain what I want?

I tried something with a condition like this in `changeGroup()`

```
if (this.groupValue.length == 0) {
   this.transform(this.usersList, '', this.groupValue)
}
```

Also, is this a good way to filter a table? I tried avoiding `pipe filters`. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Java != Javascript ...

Comment: Oups, my mistake! I wasn't paying attention :D modified.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED!!**

You are deleting items from the original Array therefore you no longer have the data.

You can use an immutable approach so using a spread operator create a new version of that array which you then splice and then when the checkbox is unchecked you reset the array back to the original value.

```
originalArray = [1,2,3,4]
newArray = [...array]
```

I would then do an ngFor using the `newArray` variable and **not** the original variable, this means your table will react to the modified array but you will always have the originalArray as a reference.

Below is an updated snippet of the transform method.

```
transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {

    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }

    if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
      return this.newArray = [...this.usersList.slice()];
    }

    this.newArray = items.filter(singleItem => {
      return (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && value.indexOf(singleItem[field]) >= 0);
    });

    return this.newArray
  }
}
```

Comment: I did a copy of the original array, but it's not working. Can you please take a look at my code? Because I don't understand much from yours.

Comment: Sure let me do that for you

Answer (score 0):

try changing like this, this should work.

```
...
if (this.groupValue.length == 0) {
  this.transform(this.usersList, '', this.groupValue)
}
...

...
if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
    this.newArray = this.usersList.slice()
    return this.newArray
}
...
```

Comment: If I use more filters at the time, it won't work anymore.